# Cannot get principal in SecurityUtils.getSubject()

Tags: java, shiro

Using Shiro, when login

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<RestResult> login(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result,
                                            HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        Result result = userService.login(user.getName(), user.getPassword());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(user.getName(), user.getPassword(), false,
                            request.getRemoteHost());
            subject.login(token);
        }
        return result.toResponseEntity();
    }
```

and in logout method:

```
   @RequestMapping("/logout")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<RestResult> logout(HttpSession session) {
    Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    subject.logout();
    return Result.success().build();
}
```

the snippet seems OK，but in the logout method, members in the subject as below,
[image]

as the picture indicates the principal is null, so, what's the matter?

Comment: Are you using the logout filter?  If so, the principal will be null by the time your code executes (as the filter would have already been called)

Comment: @Brian Demers  Did not config the logout filter in the shiro.xml file